# How to set empty search to load homepage template and not index.php

Tags: search

When an empty search is submitted, it loads the themes index.php.

I'm using a template for the homepage and have set this page under Settings -> Reading -> Static Page.

But the empty search still results in the default theme index.php page.

How do I fix this?

Ben

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Template Hierarchy in Codex? Look at `search.php`.

Comment: I have looked but I'm unable to find a solution, I also tried to delete the index file but then it just loads a blank page.

Comment: Why did you delete the `index.php` file? If you ain't got an `index.php/index.html` file nothing will load ... of course.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that...

In the end I just enabled search when the string is empty, using the function below.

`function make_blank_search ($query){
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']==''){  //if search parameter is blank, do not return false
        $wp_query->set('s',' ');
        $wp_query->is_search=true;
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','make_blank_search');`

Comment: Please update your question with it, if it is further info. If it is an answer, then please add it as such.